# British slang of using "that is" at the end of a sentence

Tags: slang

I've been trying to find examples or proofs that this expression actually exists but I just can't find any. 
I've heard it somewhere some time ago and it stuck in my head, and now I'm worried if it's even an expression people use.

Example: "A: Woah, did you see that Lambo?? B: Yes mate, great car that is!" With the stress/emphasis on the "that".

It is of course supposed to mean "that is a great car", but the slang would be to reverse the two parts of the sentence

Comment: It does exist. It's not slang though.

Comment: Sounds a bit Welsh.

Comment: Nice car, that is; fat man, he is; big fool, you are. Welsh regional.

Comment: Yes, the British do throw in "that is" for emphasis. It is spoken rather than written but it is not slang.

Comment: Lambie, that's a different thing from what the OP is asking.

Comment: A nice man, he is. She's a bright lass, she is. A nice car, that is. Same idea. The only difference is that the noun is used instead of the pronoun. I believe it's spoken and marked as non-U.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No it is not. That is is not added to anything. It is part of an inversion: Nice car that is. = That is a nice car.

Answer (score 1):

I believe  [Michael Harvey](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/46805/michael-harvey) has found the answer: adding "that is" in spoken English is indeed still used mostly in Wales.

Comment: It is not an addition. **Nice hotel that is**. is an **inversion of**: That is a nice hotel.

Comment: Perhaps sometimes it is an inversion, but the form "That's a nice hotel, that is" is also found, which can't be understood as an inversion.